# Regular expression targeting numbered list is not working

Tags: python, regex

The string I'm testing against:

```
First-line normal.
1. First item
2. Second item
3. Third item
4. Fourth item... 4. Should not remove
5. Fifth item
6. Sixth item
7. Seventh item
8. Eight item
9. Ninth item
```

Code is:

```
def remove_lists(string):
    return re.sub(r'^\d+\. ','',string,re.MULTILINE)
```

I'm expecting this to remove all the numbered starts of each line, resulting in:

```
First-line normal.
First item
Second item
Third item
Fourth item... 4. Should not remove
Fifth item
Sixth item
Seventh item
Eight item
Ninth item
```

However, it doesn't remove anything! If I remove the carat from the start of the line, it removes all but the last two items (no idea why!) but it also removes the 'should not remove'.

I've tested this on regexr.com, and pythex.org, and it works correctly on both sites. What is going on???

Comment: You need `return re.sub(r'^\d+\. ','',string, flags=re.MULTILINE)`

Comment: Thank you!!! I can't believe I missed that.